# Незакрываемое приложение на Delphi

Tags: delphi

Как сделать так, что бы приложение нельзя было закрыть?
Или хотя бы можно сделать так, что бы нельзя было закрыть с помощью Alt + F4?

Comment: Никак. Можно все равно будет закрыть диспетчером задач, отладчиком, написанием своего драйвера. В любом случае остается возможность выдернуть шнур с сети.

Comment: Ну хотя бы можно сделать так, что бы нельзя было закрыть с помощью Alt + F4?

Comment: это можно.

Comment: В общем-то, можно написать прогу, которая будет просто диспетчер задач блокировать, и не будет закрываться обычным способом, а закроется лишь при определённых условиях (если именно это надо). Или, как вариант, написать прогу, чтобы она без формы была (если нужна её работа в невидимом режиме), но тогда придётся диспетчер блокировать, т. к. процесс можно будет завершить, но в списке задач такой программы не будет видно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У формы есть событие OnClose. Оно вызывается, когда форму пытаются закрыть. И в нее передаются параметр `var Action: TCloseAction`.  Ему можно присвоить одно из значений, приведенных [здесь](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TCloseAction).
Вам нужен код вида

```
procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caNone;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Через ActionManager нужно отловить нажатие ALT+F4

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать фейковое закрытие программы с помощью form.hide
Программа будет работать в невидимом режиме

Comment: программа в таком случае все-равно отлично видно на панели задач. и ничего не мешает пользователю закрыть ее нажав правой кнопкой мыши и выбрать > закрыть..  чтобы это запретить надо использовать Action := caNone;...   иногда запрет на закрытие программы делается для того чтобы успеть выполнить какую-то операцию связанную с транзакцией... поэтому нельзя оставлять шансов пользователю в этот момент закрыть приложение.

Comment: Можно ещё и убрать с панели задач :)